# Failed edit data with jpa, value null but its exist when try to print it out

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have use case:

1. `book` table to `book_category` table with `many-to-one`
2. `book_category` table to `book` table with `one-to-many`
3. `book` table with `author` table with `many-to-many` which persist in `book_author` table (consist of `book_id` and `author_id`)

here is how I declare the `entity` and the `dto`:

**Book**

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false)
    private String year;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
      name = "book_author",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Author> author;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
    private BookCategory category;
}
```

**Author**

```
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "author",
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
        )
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Book> book;
}
```

**AuthorDto**

```
public class AuthorDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

**BookDto**

```
public class BookDto {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String year;
    private Set<AuthorDto> author;
    private String category;
}
```

**BookServiceImplementation**

```
    @Override
    public BookDto save(BookDto bookDto) throws Exception {
        try {
            Book book = new Book();
            generateBook(book, bookDto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public BookDto editById(Long id, BookDto bookDto) throws Exception {
        try {
            Book book = bookDao.findById(id).get();
            generateBook(book, bookDto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private BookDto generateBook(Book book, BookDto bookDto) throws Exception {
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(bookDto, book, "id", "author", "category");
            BookCategory bookCategory = bookCategoryDao.findByCategory(bookDto.getCategory());

            Set<Author> dataAuthor = new HashSet<Author>();
            Set<AuthorDto> dataAuthorDto = new HashSet<AuthorDto>();
            bookDto.getAuthor().iterator().forEachRemaining(dataAuthorDto::add);

            for (AuthorDto authorDto : dataAuthorDto) {
                Author author = authorDao.findByNameAndAddress(authorDto.getName(), authorDto.getAddress());
                if (null == author) {
                    author = new Author();
                    System.out.println("null"); // this printed, means that author is null
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(authorDto, author, "id");
                }

                System.out.println(author.getName()); // this printed, the copied of the name from dto to entity

                dataAuthor.add(author);
            }

            book.setAuthor(dataAuthor);
            book.setCategory(bookCategory);
            bookDao.save(book);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

here is the sample `json` for input data to do `save/update` book:

```
{
    "title": "book1",
    "year": "2013",
    "author": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "address": "LA"
        }
    ],
    "category": "science"
}
```

**Current Behaviour**

1. save new `book`, with multi `author`, if the `author` in the `json` **exist** in db, it will not saved as new data. But, if the `author` in the `json` **doesn't exist** in db, it will be saved to author table. Say I have book with title as `book1`. `book1` have `john` and `mary` as the `author`. `john` already exist in `author` table. So, when do insert data, `john` wont saved again in the table, only `mary` will saved.

**Problem**

1. Problem is when do `edit/update`. If I have `book2` with `alex` as the `author`. Then, I want to change the `author` into `john`, this case could **work** because `john` **already exist** in db. But, if I change `alex` to `lucy` (which `lucy` is **not exist** in author table), it will throw error. Here is the error: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "address" violates not-null constraint. Detail: Failing row contains (17, null, null).`

What goes wrong here?

Comment: (1) Did you try debugging the code to see what entries `dataAuthor` actually contains? (2) Does it work when you change `CascadeType.PERSIST` on `Book.author` to `{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`?

Comment: yes it works with `{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`, would you like to answer it? so I could accept as the accepted answer. thank you